# sentry multiple projects for one service: combine into one sentry project or use multiple sentry projects?

Tags: sentry, distributed-tracing

my company is running one service comprised of multiple components:

- react (nextjs)
- react-native
- flask server
- fast-api server

Would it be a good idea to combine them into one 'sentry project'?
Currently, distributed-tracing (sentry-performance) seems to miss a lot of inter-project info

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same question. Tracing doesnt seem to work for my front end and back end and I'm wondering if it's because they're in two separate projects.